# Command-prompt wildcards for digits?

Tags: command-line

Is there any wildcard for a digit in the command-prompt?

For example,

```
dir *.1*
```

Will list all files whose extensions start with 1.

Comment: Are you sure you mean MS-DOS? Because as far as I know, MS-DOS used `?` as a wildcard character, not `*`. Perhaps you mean the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) instead?

Comment: MS-DOS supports both ? (for single character substitution) and * (for multi-character substitution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MS-DOS supports only two wildcard characters (based on CP/M). They're "*", indicating any sequence of characters, and "?", indicating a single character. There is no distinction of alphabets and numerals in the wildcards and there is no support for regular expressions to constrain the wildcard to digits.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your *literal* question is 'no' - but if your real question is:

> **Can I somehow select only files containing a digit in their name under cmd?**

then if it's anything nt based (more specifically **W2k plus**) yes it can be done. 
The trick is to use `findstr`, which supports simple regexes, to filter out the results.
`dir /b  |findstr /r "\.[0-9]"` will give you results similar to what `dir` in your example would. This means it will also return `file.1st.second` (as dir would).
Small issue here is it will only list file names, but even that can be resolved:
`for /f %F in ('dir /b  ^|findstr /r "\.[0-9]"') do @echo %~ftzaF` will print your listing nicely formatted `dir` style. **Note it has to be run in current directory!**

**OR** (*what I would recommend*)
if you have `powershell` available (or you're willing to install it) fire it up and exec:
`gi .\* |? {$_.name -match "\.[0-9]"}`

**Edited** as per OP comment:

This will enumerate files using `for /r`:
Simplest, but very slow (practically unusable for anything but few files), as it runs `findstr` for every line:

`for /r "c:\temp" %F in (*) do @echo %~nxF | findstr /r "\.[0-9]" && echo %F`

More complex, but fast (uses specially prepared strings to allow piping to single instance of `findstr`:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=* eol=*" %F in ('^(for /r "directory_root" %F in ^(*^) do @echo %~nxF*%~dpnxF^) ^|findstr /r "\.[0-9].*\*"') do @echo %F
```

or (functionally the same, but easier to read :>)

```
(for /r "directory_root" %F in (*) do @echo %~nxF*%~dpnxF) | for /f "tokens=2 delims=* eol=*" %F in ('findstr /r "\.[0-9].*\*"') do @echo %F
```

***All examples as run directly from command line***

Comment: well, I'm not using dir specifically. Actually need to loop over files dos batch files using the `for /r`.

Comment: @Archival Still applicable, see my edit.